# Does HBase have it's own structured data (on HDFS)or can it execute on unstructured data on HDFS

Tags: hadoop, hive, hbase

I am cutting my teeth into **Hadoop ecosystem** and have fairly good knowledge of MR, YARN and HDFS.
I am exploring other parts of the ecosystem. I believe HiveQL can be run on HBase in SQL like fashion, and in near real time. If that is so, I believe there *is a need to transform unstructured data on HDFS into structured data so that relatively fast queries in HQL can be run*. Does this mean data is in HDFS in unstructured form, and then replicated in structured form on HDFS for use by HBase and HQL?
Also, can HiveQL be run directly on unstructured data on HDFS in batch mode(hours.. similar time as Java running as MR job)?

Answer (score 0):

HBase is a key-value store. It doesn't support SQL.

Answer (score 0):

Answer for your question 1 : ***I believe there is a need to transform unstructured data on HDFS into structured data so that relatively fast queries in HQL can be run***

> HIVE can process unstructured data by converting it into structured data. It offers a simple way to apply structure to large amounts of unstructured data, and then perform batch SQL-like queries on that data.

Data can be read from a variety of formats, from unstructured flat files with comma or space-separated text, to semi-structured JSON files, to structured HBase tables.

Look at this article [Log Analysis](http://bluecanarydata.com/hive-for-un-structured-data/) on how to convert unstructured log file into structured data and process it.

Answer for your question 2 :***Can HiveQL be run directly on unstructured data on HDFS in batch mode(hours.. similar time as Java running as MR job)?***

HiveQL cannot directly run on unstructured data. Data should be converted into structured form before processing it. Refer to above example of Log Analysis.

Answer (score 0):

HiveQL cannot run on semi structured data (data in more than one formats). All data on HDFS must be in same format. The format can be specified as metadata in a database used by Hive, which it uses to figure out the structure of data in HDFS. This is executed as map reduce job on HDFS and is indeed long running.
PIG is what is needed to run on HDFS with data in numerous formats. Hive cannot do it. PIG can do it since it is programmatic style.
You can load semi structured data into HBase using a map reduce job. Then run Hive in near real time on HBase.